# Concrete5 form submission error in ie

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, concrete5

I have a form on a site that when submitted, tells the user there was an unknown error, and could not complete the submission. However, it does submit the form still. As far as i can tell, it only happens in IE8 and IE11.

When I look in the console heres an error that I get:

> "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'hasErrors' of undefined or null
>   reference "File: certificate-of-insurance, Line: 413, Column:4"

The site is being forced to run using the ie7 engine with:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

EDIT:

Fixed it by updating that meta tag to:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=ie9" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like forcing the browser into IE7 was breaking everything, for good reason. updating the meta tag to this fixed it:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=ie9" />`